# Usage of CheckAbort[]

Tags: functions

I am calling a function that I terminate using `TimeConstrained[]` if the function doesn't complete in some time. Since `TimeConstrained[]` returns `$Aborted`, I thought I will use `CheckAbort[]` to test for Abort signal and return a default value on failure. I am unable to understand the behavior of CheckAbort[]. As `Abort[]` and `TimeContrained[]` both return the special symbol `$Aborted`, I assumed that the behavior would be the same. I expected the variable `test` to have value `0` in both cases below but the behavior is confusing.

```
test = CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[Pause[2], 1], 0]
test = CheckAbort[Abort[], 0]
```

Output:

```
$Aborted
0
```

Comment: If the abort signal is not crucial for your application, you could also use the third argument to _TimeConstrained_: `TimeConstrained[Pause[2], 1, 0]`.

Comment: While the underlying assumption is perfectly reasonable, this issue of `TimeConstrained` and `CheckAbort` not being on speaking terms is a long-standing one. I am optimistic that it will finally resolved in the version 12.2 time frame. For now the approach in the response by @Nasser seems like a viable workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to throw an Abort[] when it times out to catch it.

```
res = CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[Pause[2], 1, Abort[]], 0]

(*0*)
```

or

```
res = CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[Pause[2], 1, Abort[]],"Oh no, timed out"]
(* Oh no, timed out *)
```